# Limiting OpenVZ SMTP Per Hour

Tags: smtp, openvz

How would I limit SMTP connections per hour on the host node for a /24 block? For example, I want to limit it to 50 emails per hour.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

iptables supports connection/rate limit. From iptables man page:

> connlimit
>          Allows you to restrict the number of parallel connections to a server per client IP address (or client address block).

```
   [!] --connlimit-above n
          Match if the number of existing connections is (not) above n.

   --connlimit-mask prefix_length
          Group hosts using the prefix length. For IPv4, this must be a number between (including) 0 and 32. For IPv6, between 0 and 128.

   Examples:

   # allow 2 telnet connections per client host
          iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 23 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 2 -j REJECT

   # you can also match the other way around:
          iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 23 -m connlimit ! --connlimit-above 2 -j ACCEPT

   # limit the number of parallel HTTP requests to 16 per class C sized network (24 bit netmask)
          iptables -p tcp --syn --dport 80 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 16 --connlimit-mask 24 -j REJECT

   # limit the number of parallel HTTP requests to 16 for the link local network
          (ipv6) ip6tables -p tcp --syn --dport 80 -s fe80::/64 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 16 --connlimit-mask 64 -j REJECT
```

> limit
>          This  module  matches  at  a limited rate using a token bucket filter.  A rule using this extension will match until this limit is reached (unless the ‘!’ flag is used).  It can be used in combination with the LOG target to give limited
>          logging, for example.

```
   --limit rate[/second|/minute|/hour|/day]
          Maximum average matching rate: specified as a number, with an optional ‘/second’, ‘/minute’, ‘/hour’, or ‘/day’ suffix; the default is 3/hour.

   --limit-burst number
          Maximum initial number of packets to match: this number gets recharged by one every time the limit specified above is not reached, up to this number; the default is 5.
```

Comment: Just a minor footnote: although not a technique many spammers use, a single TCP connection can be used to deliver multiple individual messages.

Comment: Yes, that is true. 1 SMTP connection != One e-mail

Comment: Great thank you. What would you advise / suggest?